# CSS: Rotated drop shadow on right side of box

Tags: html, shadow, css

I have a fixed, 100% height menu on the left and I need to create a shadow effect on its right side that would disappear after while.

See the figure that illustrates this.

[image]

How to create this effect?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7787/

HTML:

```
<nav id="main-menu">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <a href="#">A</a>
  <a href="#">B</a>
  <a href="#">C</a>
  <a href="#">D</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#main-menu {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #b4bac1;
}
```

Comment: If you have your psd just copy the values of your shadow and paste on any shadow generator it definitely will help.

Comment: @Benjamin That's the easy part of the question. The hard part is the gradual vertical fade out of the shadow.

Comment: I found this examply while googling. http://jsfiddle.net/vBuxt/1/ Not exactly what you want but I think you can modify it to your needs.

Comment: Your fiddle has nothing to do with this issue...did you link the wrong one.

Comment: Sorry, Fiddle updated, there was a wrong link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS3: `box-shadow` and `transform`.

In the example below the `box-shadow` is applied to a pseudo element of `.menuContainer` which sits underneath the `.menu` element and is rotated by `1°` using CSS3s `rotate()` transform property.

```css
html,body {  /* This is only here to allow the menu to stretch to 100% */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.menuContainer {
    position: relative;    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
.menuContainer::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;   
    z-index: 1; 
    top: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -7px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 10px 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 100px;    
    transform: rotate(1deg);
}
.menu {
    background: #f00;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuContainer">
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/z1k559z4/17/)

Comment: This doesn't fade out after while, but keeps on being constant from the top to the bottom.

Comment: I think you are misreading the question. OP wants a shadow that gradualy fades out verticaly. There is no animation mentioned.

Comment: Also, I don't think the animation is a requirement...it's more of the fact that the box-shadow is not consistent in opacity from bottom to top. It's a 'corner-lift' shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You could fake it with a pseudo-element rather than using a box-shadow as follows

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3o2gh3e6/1/)

**CSS**

```
#main-menu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: pink;
}

#main-menu:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    height:100%;
    width:5%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

Comment: When using a linear gradient, how to make it blurry on the edge? Now the edges are sharp.

Comment: You could try a radial gradient but gradients don't take blurs.